# CSS only Responsive multi-level menu is not working on safari

Tags: css, sass, safari

I am trying to use this Mega menu, but I want to know what is the problem that safari doesn't support this menu and doesn't open the menu when clicking on it.
[Here is the codepen link](https://codepen.io/vixxofsweden/pen/xxGGYOE)
I think this part is the problem not oppening the menu
`

```
 // FUNCTIONALITY: Open mega menu
        &:focus {
          ~ ul {
            display: flex;
            transform-origin: top;
            animation: dropdown .2s ease-out;
          }
        }
```

`

Do we have a list to check if any CSS att. is not compatible with Safari or not?
Or is it a way to make this menu work on Safari by just changing some parts of the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
it was an easy fix.
an element that you want to have *:focus* on it, should have tabindex att like:

```
 <a href="#" class="hide" tabindex="1">first</a>
 <a href="#" class="show" tabindex="2">second</a>
```

Then it will work on Safari and other browsers.